# Require receipts when sending Outlook email by Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32

Simple lines to send Outlook email by Python,

referencing from [Send email through Python using Outlook 2016 without opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926514/send-email-through-python-using-outlook-2016-without-opening-it)

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'contact@sample.com'
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.Body = 'Message body'

mail.Send()
```

Is it possible to require Delivery Receipt and Read Receipt when sending an email? What would be the good way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use [ReadReceiptRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171860(v=office.11)) & [OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested property MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.originatordeliveryreportrequested)

*Example*

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "0m3r@Email.com"
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.Body = 'Message body'
# request read receipt
mail.ReadReceiptRequested = True
# request delivery receipt
mail.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
mail.Send()
```